# Error when using DTCoreText to display HTML code

Tags: ios, dtcoretext

I use DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder of DTCoreText to display HTML code in UITableViewCell. But it has an error.
This is my code:

```
NSDictionary *builderOptions = @{DTDefaultFontFamily: @"Helvetica"};
DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder *stringBuilder = [[DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder alloc] initWithHTML:[word[@"name"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:builderOptions documentAttributes:nil];
NSAttributedString *stringAttri = [stringBuilder generatedAttributedString];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = stringAttri;
```

This is error:

```
    [__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f7bd1ba60
2015-06-06 11:16:38.898 PhrasalVerb[786:18798] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f7bd1ba60'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Turns out I was trying to set the text on a UILabel and not a DTAttributedLabel.